# Pass Custom Init Parameter through Storyboard Segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, segue

I'm somewhat new to the concept of custom initializers, so I'm having a hard time understanding if what Im trying to do is possible.

I'm using source code to create a messaging app. All the code was written without the use of storyboards, which I'd now like to implement.

The init as it is implemented in the source code is this:

```
init(chat: Chat) {
    self.chat = chat
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    title = chat.user.name
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, the original code passed a custom init parameter this way:

```
 let chat = chats[indexPath.row]
    let chatViewController = MessagesViewController(chat: chat)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
```

What I tried doing was simply creating a storyboard UIViewController, setting the class to the original code, that is, setting the storyboard ViewController to: MessagesViewController, then perform a segue. Like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "ToMessages" {
        var messagesViewController: MessagesViewController = segue.destinationViewController as MessagesViewController
        let chat = chats[indexPath.row]
        messagesViewController.chat = chat
    }
```

Then `performSegueWithIdentifier("ToMessages", sender: self)`

When I do this I get this fatal error: `fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:`

From my research and understanding of the original source code, the reason is because I am not initializing the `chat` parameter. I realize I may not be on the right track, if so an idea of where to go from here will be appreciated.

If I am correct about whats going on, then my specific question is how to implement parameters in a prepareForSegue method, something like:

```
var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as MessagesViewController(chat: chat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `init` code as follows

```
init(chat: Chat) {
    self.chat = chat
    super.init()
    title = chat.user.name
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

`init(coder:)` is called whenever a `UIViewController` is created via `Storyboard`. In your case the override is called in which you have written a `fatalError()` to make it fail, the error that you are getting when executing.

Comment: It seems I get this error: `Property self.chat not initialized at super.init call`

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't because you're not initializing the chat parameter, it's because you haven't called super in initWithCoder. That is the method that's called for a view coming out of the storyboard, so you'll just have to set the chat property rather than using a custom initializer, like you show in your last code snippet. Since you're not doing anything in the int methods, you can just delete them all. If you need to have them in there for some other purpose, then just delete the "fatal error" line from initWithCoder, and replace it with a call to super.